# Check personalization views on a component without AB tests

Tags: xdb, personalization, content-testing

What should be done in order for one to check how many views a personalized view of a component has x the default version of that same component?

This component is on a homepage of a website and there is a lot of traffic on it and data is being collected but we are not seeing anything in the Personalized experience dialog.

Also I read this [article](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-personalized-experience-dialog-box.html) where it says that in order for one to see data it's needed that the component has AB tests or was tested to show data there. Is that really the case? Is it not possible to see personalized analytics without AB tests? There has got to be an easier way around that

[image]

This is on Sitecore 8.1 BTW

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the reach. What you won't get is the effect as that's calculated based on the active test. Below is an example screenshot of a Personalization rule running on Sitecore 8.1, but without active test. So you get Reach %, but not effect.

Also as mentioned in the link you had https://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-personalized-experience-dialog-box.html

> Reach = (Visitors that match the condition/All visitors) x 100
>
> If the personalization rule is part of an active test, the reach is calculated for the full period that the test has run. If the personalization rule is not part of an active test, the reach is shown based on the last 30 days.

So Reach is possible to get without active test, effect isn't.

[image: Personalization dialog from 8.1]

Comment: did you have to enable anything? I mean even reach is not showing in my case

Comment: @Diego As far as i remember there is a certain delay in receiving data from analytics database, depending on your configuation. In our case we had to wait around 6 hours for test or any reaches to actually show some data.